# make to show Japanese language on android device

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, languages

I install app which supports Japanese language. But in my phone, it didn't show the Japanese language. My phone is sony xperia z. How should I make to see Japanese language.

Thanks.

Comment: Japanese is included **by default** in your device. Did you check the language setting to make sure that the language is not available?

Comment: Yes. I did. There is no Japanese language in my device. There is only Japanese keyboard. when I typed with Japanese kb, it shows blank.